# React Child Component does not update properties passed from Parent Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a parent component and a child component as function components in react.

**Parent Component**

```
const Parent = () => {

    const selectedProduct = 0;
    //const [servicesList, setServicesList] = useState<IService[]>([]);
    var servicesList = [] as IService[];
    var operationalProcessSelector = [] as IOperationalProcessSelector[];


    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchServicesList(840);
    }, []);

    const fetchServicesList = async (quotationId: number) => {

        const SERVICE_LIST_API_URL = `API URL...`;
        
        await axios.get(SERVICE_LIST_API_URL, {headers:API_REQ_HEADERS})
            .then((response:any)=>{

                if(response && response.data && response.data.length > 0 && response.data[0]){
                    
                    let product = response.data[selectedProduct];
                    let operationalProcesses = product.OperationalProcess;

                    updateServiceList(operationalProcesses);

                }

            });

    };

    const updateServiceList = (operationalProcesses: any) => {

        operationalProcesses.forEach((operationalProcessItem: any)=>{
            operationalProcessItem.Services.forEach((serviceItem: any) => {
                serviceItem.LineEditState = 'edit';
                serviceItem.ShowContent = true;
            });
        });

        const flattenedArray: IService[] = operationalProcesses.reduce(
                (accumulator: IService[], value: any) => accumulator.concat(value.Services), 
                [] as IService[]);

        //servicesList(flattenedArray);
        servicesList = flattenedArray;
        console.log('Update Services', servicesList); // It retrieves and outputs data here
    };



    return <ServiceGrid OperationalProcessSelector={operationalProcessSelector} />
}

export default Parent
```

**Child Component**

```
const ServiceGrid = (props: Prop) => {
    
    console.log("Component ServiceGrid generated");

    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState<IService[]>(props.ServicesList);

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('component', tableData); // It does not return the value
    });






  return (
        
        <div>{tableData.map((e: any)=>e.childData)}</div> // It does not render the value here
  );
  
};

export default ServiceGrid;

interface Prop {
    OperationalProcessSelector: IOperationalProcessSelector[],
    ServicesList: IService[]
}
```

Question: why `tableData` in child component does not load?

I am not sure whether I should use State or just a plain variable here. But once I receive the value to the child, I might update the child variable and it should automatically reflect in the child component.

**PS:**
I have tried useState() in both parent and child components as well.

**Parent Component variables**

```
const [servicesList, setServicesList] = useState<IService[]>([]);
const [operationalProcessSelector, setOperationalProcessSelector] = useState<IOperationalProcessSelector[]>([]);
```

even after using setTableData function it does not reflect.

**Child Component variables**

```
useEffect(()=>{
        setTableData(props.ServicesList);
        // setOperationalProcessSelector(props.OperationalProcessSelector);
        console.log('component', props.ServicesList);
    }, []);
```

Comment: You should definitively use a state variable and don't copy props in state otherwise, at props update, you should set state again using an `useEffect`.

Comment: Because you don't call `setTableData` so `tableData ` don't have value

Comment: Even after setting tableData using setTableData it does not update the value.  - Updated the question.

Comment: Hello @Kirk, as GiovanniEsposito and Viet explained to you well. Rather than using useEffect in the child component, use useEffect in the parent component. Because the main problem is the list you are passing the child component is modifying after the parent and child component getting rendered. And as once parent component is rendered, it's not re-rendering again so the list you are passing is not getting passed to the child component after manipulation. So just use the list state variable of the component so whenever the list gets changed child component will be re-rendered with a new value.

Comment: Try using operationalProcessSelector and servicesList  as state variable for Parent.

Comment: @ZouhairDre, I have tried using state variable as well before. Did not result me anything possitive, Updated the answer fyi

Answer (score 0):

you should pass `props.ServicesList` to `useEffect` dependency array.

```js
useEffect(()=>{
        setTableData(props.ServicesList);
        // setOperationalProcessSelector(props.OperationalProcessSelector);
        console.log('component', props.ServicesList);
    }, [props.ServicesList]);
```